# Create PDF file with data from firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, pdf-generation

I have created a table from Firebase using ListViewBuilder. I also want to view the table in the form of PDF but I have no idea on how to do that. I checked some examples but non of them satisfies what I'm looking for.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore...
    builder: (context, snapshot){
         if(snapshot.hasData){
           return Row(
              children:[
               LitView.Builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  builder: (context, index){
                   final data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                   final date = data["Day"];
                   final amount = data["Amount"];
                   return ListTile(
                      ....
                    );
                  }
                ),
                TextButton(
                   onTap:(){
                        /* I want to view the the table in PDF form on the
                         press of this button*/
                      }
                  )
              ]
           );
        }
     }
   );
```

This is the code. I want that when I press on the button, I should be able to view the table in a PDF from, and also be able to save and print the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the package `syncfusion_flutter_datagrid`. Syncfusion provides an extensive set of features such as sorting, filtering, and also PDF & Excel export. See an [offical demo](https://flutter.syncfusion.com/?_gl=1*f3kg5m*_ga*NDQ3ODkyMjYwLjE3MDQyMjU2MDY.*_ga_41J4HFMX1J*MTcwODgwNTEyMS4xNy4xLjE3MDg4MDUzNTYuMC4wLjA.#/datagrid/exporting).

The export functionality comes from separate Syncfusion packages that require a bit of custom implementation logic, partly depending on whether you are building a web or mobile app.

Comment: Thanks but still finding it difficult to implement. When I get the syncfusion_flutter_datagrid in pubspec.yaml, it gives me this error: 
The getter 'isMetaPressed' isn't defined for the class 'Hardware Keyboard'.
I don't know how to correct that